# PHP RabbitMQ - How to assign multiple messages in the queue to their own individual variables in a PHP script

Tags: php, rabbitmq

So far I can write three messages to a queue as such using this script (send.php) **Note this is taken from RabbitMQs tutorial**:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;
use PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

$msg1 = new AMQPMessage('Blue');             //I wanted this to be assigned to $color
$msg2 = new AMQPMessage('English');          //I wanted this to be assigned to $language
$msg3 = new AMQPMessage('Canada');           //I wanted this to be assigned to $country

$channel->basic_publish($msg1, '', 'hello');
$channel->basic_publish($msg2, '', 'hello');
$channel->basic_publish($msg3, '', 'hello');

echo " [x] Sent 'Hello World!'\n";

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
?>
```

This is the other script that will recieve the messages from RabbitMQ (recieve.php) **Note this is taken from RabbitMQs tutorial**:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPStreamConnection;

$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection('localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
$channel = $connection->channel();

$channel->queue_declare('hello', false, false, false, false);

echo " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C\n";

$callback = function ($msg) {
    echo ' [x] Received ', $msg->body, "\n";
};

$channel->basic_consume('hello', '', false, true, false, false, $callback);

while ($channel->is_consuming()) {
    $channel->wait();
}

$channel->close();
$connection->close();
?>
```

When I run the receive script, this is what the output looks like:

```
[*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
Blue
English
Canada
```

The issue that I am running into is getting those individual messages into their own PHP variables. I was hoping for something like this:

```
$color = $msg1->body;
$language = $msg2->body;
$country = $msg3->body;
```

I have tried going into the recieve.php file and adding in $msg1->body, $msg2->body, $msg->body into the script, but that will put all three messages into one variable.

Answer (score 0):

You may use *queue object*, questionKid.

```
/* create a queue object */
$queue = new AMQPQueue($channel);

//declare the queue
$queue->declare('myqueue');

//get the messages
$messages = $queue->get(AMQP_AUTOACK);

echo $message->getBody();
```

Credit goes to [this post](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/php/2012/amqpqueue.get.html).
There must be some way of using your channel-based approach, too.